# Android : Accessing the step counter sensor natively through jni

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-sensors

I'm trying to access sensors natively and my goal is to access to the step counter sensor in C++ through JNI.Despite the possiblity of accessing the sensors by using NDK headers like in this tuto http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html  android/sensor.h but this one doesn't give the access to all sensors (well,it has a good sampling rate compared to java methods).
Is there any  solution to access to the sensors provided in java through JNI ?

Thank you in advance !